# How to generate every combination of a Map in Scala

Tags: scala

```scala
   val monies: Map[String, Double] = Map(
    "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154,
    "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
    "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875,
    "COL-USD" -> 1.0000000,
    "ABC-XYZ" -> 1.00034500,
    "XYZ-ABC" -> 1.000345000
  )
```

I want to create a `List[Map[String, Double]]` which has every possible combination of the Map above.

In the final List of Maps, each Map must have a minimum of three currencies (i.e. any Maps with less than 3 entries must be excluded).

The Map provided may have 3 currencies or may have 50. Meaning the solution must be scalable for example if any new country was established along with a new currency.

```scala
  List(
    Map(
      "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154,
      "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
      "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875
    ),
    Map(
      "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
      "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154,
      "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875
    ),
    Map(
      "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
      "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875,
      "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154
    ), 
    Map(
      "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154,
      "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
      "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875,
      "COL-USD" -> 1.0000000,
    ),
    Map(
      "EUR-GBP" -> 0.0097373,
      "USD-EUR" -> 0.7473154,
      "GBP-USD" -> 136.6080875,
      "COL-USD" -> 1.0000000,
    ), 
    
    .... etc etc

  )
```

Please note unique can mean a different a different order of the entries. Also different length of Map size. Key must point to original values.

Comment: `Maps` don't have order so it seems all you need is all subsets of keys whose size is greater or equal than 2?

Comment: Hey :) I have been provided with a single Map and need to generate every possible combination of that Map. Then filter out any Maps which contain only two entries.

Comment: Scala seqs have a built-in combination method https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/Seq.html. Grab the keys from the map, get the combinations for each int between 3 and the size of the map and then map those combinations back to maps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all you need is this:

```scala
def getSubMaps[K, V](map: Map[K, V]): Iterator[Map[K, V]] =
  map
    .keySet
    .subsets
    .filter(keys => keys.sizeIs >= 3)
    .map(keys => keys.map(key => key -> map(key)).toMap)
```

Since the result can be too big it is better to return an `Iterator` that will lazily produce the values required. You can always call `toList` at the end if you really need all of them in memory.

---

*As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend*.